# How to use local storage value in ngif

Tags: angular

How can I use local storage variable in ng if..

I have implemented but showing me error as Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined..

Here is my code:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="localStorage.getItem(Role)==''">
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary editable-table-button btn-xs" (click)="updatetq(tq_list.cmslearntopicid
      ,tq_list.cmslearnchapterid,tq_list.topicname);">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger editable-table-button btn-xs" (click)="deletet(tq_list.cmslearntopicid);">Delete</button>
    </td>
</ng-template>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it doesnt work for me.. If role value is admin and then i want to put ngif condition it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

First of all your ngIf syntax is completely wrong, secondly you can retrive the value from localStorage and bind it

change

```
<ng-template  *ngIf="objUserData.role===''">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution.

> component.html

```
<ng-template *ngIf="getRole(Role)==''">
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary editable-table-button btn-xs" (click)="updatetq(tq_list.cmslearntopicid
      ,tq_list.cmslearnchapterid,tq_list.topicname);">Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger editable-table-button btn-xs" (click)="deletet(tq_list.cmslearntopicid);">Delete</button>
    </td>
</ng-template>
```

> component.ts

```
getRole(role){
   return localStorage.getItem(role) || ''
}
```

Comment: What about if the `getItem()`returned undefined?

Comment: @mehul , I'd suggest you don't take a habit of doing something like this, i.e calling a method in template, it will be called on each change detection, which can be really often, worst case you can fall into a sort of infinite loop. Here's just a simple sample... type (or even just click!) in the fields and check console... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2myeey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: it doesnt work for me.. If role value is admin and then i want to put ngif condition it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

your error says clearly `Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined` because the `localStorage` does not have getItem() prototypes. So you can fix this by using this below ways

- You should assign the local storage into a variable which is needs to be use in HTML
- or use a global method to read local storage values by passing `keys`. (**this one is the best way** because of global  to read the data, I have explained below )

---

**Component method:**

```
readLocalStorageValue(key)
    {
      let value =   localStorage.getItem(key);
      if(value == undefined)
        {
          value =='';
        }
       return value;
    }
```

And you HTML side should looks like below

```
*ngIf="readLocalStorageValue('Role')== ''"
```

> Note : I am not sure about the `Role` object which is used in your code. I hope it's a key of localStorage. but if it have any dynamic value, then pass `Role` object without using single quote in readLocalStorageValue method

Comment: it doesnt work for me.. If role value is admin and then i want to put ngif condition it doesnt work

Comment: Did you see my note? I told if the Role is an object instead of key then you don't need to put single quote @mehul .